# Is AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters implemented in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, pinvoke, audiotoolbox

I am trying to add buffers to a queue and would like to use the `AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters` as described in the iOS Audio Toolbox documentation. I see that it is a private extern in the MonoTouch assembly browser.

```
    [DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox")]
    private static extern AudioQueueStatus AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters......
```

Is it possible to declare this extern elsewhere in order to use it?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In general **p/invoke** declarations are all marked `private` in MonoTouch. Safer and easier to use managed alternatives are then supplied.

In this specific case the `AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters` p/invoke gets called from the public `AudioQueue.EnqueueBuffer` method. Since this is part of the code that is shared between MonoTouch and MonoMac you can see the full source code [here](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.cs#L382).

Of course you can still copy-paste the previous p/invoke declaration into your own application  and it will work too (but in some cases it might be more complex to have it interact with the related managed API).